# Sharing an atom between Clojure and Clojurescript?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Assume I have a Clojurescript namespace called main with a atom within it called state.

```
(ns main)

(atom state nil)
```

I compile my Clojurescript app, run it on a server, fire up the Clojurescript repl and then connect to my server using a browser. Everything works dandy.

In the Clojurescript repl, I can comfirm the usual

```
> (+ 1 1) 
2
> (js/alert "Hey there") //shows an alert dialog with "Hey there" in the browser
nil
> main.state
(atom nil)
```

The Clojurescript repl is great for development. So, clearly I can get and (using swap! or reset!) set the value of a Clojurescript atom from a Clojure application. I was wondering if there was a way to have a connection between the value of an atom in my Clojurescript project and a running Clojure application. Perhaps the Clojurescript client connects to a specified port and sends the result to some Clojure server waiting on that port. Simply stated, I was wondering if it might be possible to have a running server application share the value of the `state` client atom.

Why, you might ask? Well, I was thinking it would be nice to write the value of the `state` atom to a actual file (state.clj) whenever `state` is modified in the running Clojurescript application. This way, I could always have a view of the current value of `state`. I could use something like emacs `(global-auto-revert-mode t)` to make sure that state.clj buffer was always fairly recent. This is a little like having a debugger.

Beyond that, my real desire is to then make it so that the running Clojure application would also periodically poll state.clj itself. When the server detects that I modified state.clj, it would accept the modification as the new value of the Clojurescript `state` atom. It would then do something like what the Clojurescript repl does, illustrated in the following pseudo code:

```
(send-to-client-for-evaluation
  (compile-into-js 
    (reset! 
      main.state 
      the-read-string-value-of-the-content-of-state.clj)))
```

Basically, I want the ability for the server to have something akin to a shared atom between the client and the server. I want the value of `state` to be bidirectionally shared between the client and the server. Is any of this possible, or am I just dreaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just make requests to a rest API sending data in [EDN format](https://github.com/edn-format/edn), and voila! If you want to avoid polling, consider running your Jetty or Tomcat behind an Nginx instance to make use of the [Nginx HTTP Push Module](http://pushmodule.slact.net/).  I have a somewhat cobwebby example [here](https://github.com/rplevy/sayoperation) (this was pre-ClojureScript, so I wrote the client in plain JS).  And there is also [gifsockets](https://github.com/videlalvaro/gifsockets).